# What signs of life did Chekov see on the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, star-trek-beyond

[image]

In Star Trek Beyond there's a pretty cool scene where Captain Kirk and Chekov head toward the wrecked Enterprise with their prisoner, Kalana. When they see it from a distance Checkov immediately pipes up and says, "She still has power."

**How did he know the saucer section still had power? I might add, it's daytime when they see it first.**

*As a bonus question, how in the world could it still have power?*

Comment: I'm guessing someone who knows the ship intimately would be able to tell; exterior lighting, certain hatches that need power to stay open, etc.

Comment: Answer to bonus question:  It's science fiction.   They have magical objects that provide electrical power even without an engine running.   They might even be chemically based.   Someone might have come up with some ridiculous technobabble name.   Like maybe, I don't know, *batteries* or something like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote from the scene pictured above is actually

> **Chekov:** ***She may not even have power to the Bridge, Keptin.***
>
> **Kirk:** *She still has a few tricks up her sleeve. [beat] I'd bet on it.*

It's not until nighttime (and at the point when they're close enough to the ship to be able **to see and hear individual features**) that Chekov then exclaims...

> **Chekov:** *It looks like it has power*

As they enter the ship, we see that the bridge's emergency lighting is still working (albeit sporadically). That, presumably is what Chekov could see from the ground.

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are a prolific answerer. This was a fascinating find.